# Devops yaml "The term '-powershell:' is not recognized"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'd like my devops build pipeline to run PowerShell that will list files it later complains it can't find.

When I run the following I get the error:

> The term '-powershell:' is not recognized

Where did I go wrong?

```
name: Deploy Bicep files $(Build.BuildId)

trigger: none
# - main

variables:
  location: "uksouth"
  templateFile: "bicep/365Response.main.json"

pool:
  vmImage: "windows-latest"

stages:
  - stage: preDeploy
    variables:
      env: "dev"
    jobs:
      - job: listFiles
        displayName: List Files
        pool:
          vmImage: windows-2022

        steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: "-powershell: Get-ChildItem -Path '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)' -recurse"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is from PowerShell, telling you that `-powershell` is not a valid construct in PowerShell :) And it's not.

To me, that says that inside the `script` element you need a valid powershell snippet, such as:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)' -recurse
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write `-powershell:`  there.

Correct config:

```yaml
        steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: "Get-ChildItem -Path '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)' -recurse"
```

[`-powershell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet) is actually a shortcut for the task. So you can also write this instead of the above:

```
        steps:
          - powershell: "Get-ChildItem -Path '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)' -recurse"
```